# Performance: jQuery remove() vs JavaScript removeChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a table which contains about 1,500 rows.

I'm removing the table from the DOM with the following jQuery code:

```
$('#myTable').remove();
```

which takes about 300ms, creating a quite noticeable lag.

Doing the same thing with removeChild():

```
var myTable = $('#myTable')[0] ;
myTable.parentNode.removeChild(myTable);
```

takes about 30ms.

I can easy use the removeChild() version, but I was puzzled why jQuery's remove() would take so much longer? Is the removeChild() version not clearing something that jQuery is?

Demo: [jspref](http://jsperf.com/jquery-remove-vs-removechild)

Comment: After reading @dystroy's insight I went looking for a jQuery source tool. There's a great source viewer here: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) :

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

This means :

- that this function does some extra work (mainly calling `cleanData` for itself and the childs)
- that you should generally use it to avoid memory leaks

This appears clearly in the source code :

```
remove: function( selector, keepData ) {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( !selector || jQuery.filter( selector, [ elem ] ).length > 0 ) {
            if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem ) );
            }

            if ( elem.parentNode ) {
                if ( keepData && jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem ) ) {
                    setGlobalEval( getAll( elem, "script" ) );
                }
                elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Why only a part of the answer?

Comment: @Bergi I had edited. There's always an overhead related to jQuery operation. But it's not very interesting so I simplified the phrasing.

Comment: Thanks! That clearly explains the time difference. I wonder if its safe to bypass cleanData()? I don't have any jQuery events against that element.

Comment: @Kong In that case it should be safe. But if you don't see any performance problem that a user could notice, I'd recommend to keep it, because the rest of your application could thus evolve with less risk of creating a memory leak.